# i want to create this text-equation alignment but i cant figure out how

Tags: equations, align, numbering, arrays

I have this image, and i want to recreate it in latex. Equations must be aligned on the left as well as the text next to the equations must be aligned on the right and the numbering of equations must be included too. I have tried \begin{subequations} , \begin{arrays} , \begin{align} but i cant get the alignment and the numbering.

Following is the picture that I want to recreate
[image]

Following is my code without the alignment

```
"Maxwell's equations" are named for James Clark Maxwell and are as follow:

\begin{equation}
  \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{E}\quad =\quad \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}  \text{{Gauss's Law}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{B}\quad  = \quad 0  \text{{Gauss's Law for Magnetism}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \overrightarrow{\nabla} \times \overrightarrow{E}\quad  = \quad - \frac{\partial \overrightarrow{B} }{\partial t} \text {{Faraday's Law of Induction}}
\end{equation}   

\begin{equation}
   \overrightarrow{\nabla} \times \overrightarrow{B} \quad = \quad \frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}  \text{{Ampere's Circuital Law}}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is achievable using a standard `align` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

``Maxwell's equations'' are named for James Clark Maxwell and are as follow:
\begin{align}
   \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} &= \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} && 
    \text{Gauss's Law} \\
   \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} &= 0                       && 
    \text{Gauss's Law for Magnetism} \\
  \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} &= -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} && 
    \text{Faraday's Law of Induction} \\
  \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B} &= \mu_0 \biggl( \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t} + \vec{J} \biggr) && 
    \text{Ampere's Circuital Law}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now.